# How to draw lines in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to design something like

[image]

This is what I have so far:

[image]

How do I add those lines in ionic?

How do I add CSS to get the desired design in here?

This code is what I have so far:

```
<ion-slide>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img src="img/icon1.png"></img>
      <br>
      Live Outlets </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img src="img/icon2.png"></img>
      <br>
      Bills</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img src="img/icon3.png"></img>
      <br>
      Items Sold </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img src="img/icon4.png"></img>
      <br>
      Discount</div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img src="img/icon5.png"></img>
      <br>
      Customer </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img src="img/icon6.png"></img>
      <br>
      Sale</div>
  </div>

</ion-slide>
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it as a new question, rather than editing this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi this code is worked for me, check this:

```
<ion-slide>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-50">
      <img src="img/icon1.png"></img><br>
      Live Outlets
    </div>
    <div class="col col-50">
      <img src="img/icon2.png"></img>
      <br>
      Bills
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-50">
      <img src="img/icon3.png"></img>
      <br>
      Items Sold </div>
    <div class="col col-50">
      <img src="img/icon4.png"></img>
      <br>
      Discount</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col  col-50">
      <img src="img/icon5.png"></img>
      <br>
      Customer </div>
    <div class="col  col-50">
      <img src="img/icon6.png"></img>
      <br>
      Sale</div>
  </div>
</ion-slide>
```

and in your `style.css` file add an extra css property as:

```
.col{
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

having any queries, please reply